# auto-deploy .war to remote jboss4.2.3.GA fail using hudson deploy plugin

Tags: deployment, jboss, hudson, system-properties

I'm using hudson-deploy plugin, to auto-deploy my `.war` file to a remote `jboss4.2.3.GA`.
When I set the port lower than `10000`, it works, for example:

```
http://10.78.68.210:8080/
```

But our system is using port `17200`, so the url should be

```
http://10.78.68.210:17200
```

this time, auto-deploy failed. the error message is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:117200
    at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:118)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss4xRemoteDeployer.buildSocketAddressForDeployableServer(JBoss4xRemoteDeployer.java:269)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss4xRemoteDeployer.<init>(JBoss4xRemoteDeployer.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss4xRemoteDeployer.<init>(JBoss4xRemoteDeployer.java:117)
    ... 27 more
```

i saw a unexpected "117200" above, rather than "17200"

so i checked the source code:

```
String portStr = configuration.getPropertyValue(JBossPropertySet.REMOTEDEPLOY_PORT);
if (portStr == null)
{
    portStr = "1" + configuration.getPropertyValue(ServletPropertySet.PORT);
}
```

and

```
String REMOTEDEPLOY_PORT = "cargo.jboss.remotedeploy.port";
```

since the virable portStr always returned `null`, the portStr then be set to "1"+"17200", as a result "117200"

How can I let hudson-deploy load a valued `cargo.jboss.remotedeploy.port` property? I tried everything but failed every time.

thanks a lot!